# Executando uma função Python de modo assíncrono com Celery

Tags: python, assincronismo

Tenho a função `test()` que demora muito e quero executá-la assincronamente. Coloquei o `decorator` do Celery na mesma conforme abaixo:

```
from celery import task

@task
def test():
    (...)
    return 'done1
```

E a executo fazendo:

```
test.delay()
```

Quando executo meu programa ela não é colocada em segundo plano conforme esperado, ela executa normamente de modo síncrono. Estou esquecendo de algo relacionado ao Celery?

Comment: Leia: [Requisitos básicos para rodar aplicação utilizando o Celery](https://medium.com/luizalabs/executando-processos-em-background-com-django-e-celery-5ade867e1bf3)

Comment: Para quem estiver com dificuldades para entender o Celery, este link também me ajudou bastante: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/v4.2.1/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html